# Set monitor "boundaries" on OSX?

Tags: macos, display, resolution

I have a Dell 23" monitor. It got damaged and now approximately 7 centimeters from the right is completely black - all the way vertically (I guess pixels got burned or something), and I cannot use that area of the screen.

Is there any way to "resize" the amount of screen used by the operating system? So it will act as if this area did not even exist?

Image for demonstration:

[image]

(Red are is the "dead" zone which I want to exclude)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broken laptop screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/797538/broken-laptop-screen)

Comment: @Burgi nonsense. Look at the replies there - and the context of the question. I am sure that this is a monitor issue, and looking for an OS-related fix. We are not even looking for the same solution. I'm using OSX, too. How is this a duplicate? -_-